# Would final users have to download android app again when app is moved from a Google play account to another?

Tags: android, google-play

Suppose you have an android application associated to some account in Google Play. Then, this account's onwer decide to disassociate such app from his/her account.
So, I would have to upload (don't know for sure) this app to Google Play again using a new account owner.

Would end users have to download app again (from this new account)? Or app updates would still work 'automatically'?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the support to move an app from one developer account to another. Like that, the users won't have to download the app again and you even keep all the statistics in the playstore.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247